# Xview Memory Buffer in C

Tags: c, user-interface, memory, x11, xserver

I am using a program written in C and Fortran that uses Xview to create GUIs. When I do some calculations in the program, occasionally I receive the following error which displays as a panel and halts the program:

"Notice: Insertion failed - The memory buffer is full. If this is an isolated case, you can circumvent this condition by undoing the operation you just performed, storing the contents of the subwindow to a file using the text menu, and then redoing the operation. Or, you can change the size of this buffer by changing the appropriate value in the .Xdefaults file (Text.MaxDocumentSize)."

There is a button at the bottom "Continue" and clicking it allows the program to continue without issue.

I am running a program that needs to be automated, and I cannot have the program halt and require user input. Does anyone know how to remove this notice from popping up and halting the program? I have tracked this down to something inside Xview itself and not the program I am using.

I have tried editing the .Xdefaults file and increasing the Text.MaxDocumentSize value, but this did not work.

I have also tried writing C++ programs that will continuously pass the "Enter" command to the X-Window to try to get around this when the notice panel pops up, but this did not work with Xview. It does work with other programs in X11 though.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a work-around for this?

Comment: I would extract the relevant Fortran routines from your application's source code, and make a batch program out of it. Of course, that might take time.

Answer (score 1):

open your editor

edit the .Xdefaults file (probably in your home directory)

scroll down to the text: `Text.MaxDocumentSize`

this text is followed by a value.  Increase that value, say, double it.

save the .Xdefaults file

exit the editor.

problem is solved unless you make REALLY LARGE source files, then you may want to quad the value rather than just doubling it.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, but it did not work. I'm not sure if Xview is not reading my .Xdefaults file in my home directory. Is there a way to suppress this message entirely? Is there some value I can set using a Xview command?

Comment: did you also exit X and re-start it?  so the new version of the .Xdefaults file is read?

Comment: did you check the system .Xdefaults file to assure it is reading the .Xdefaults file of the currently logged in user?